# What does chmod stand for?

Tags: utilities, history

In order to memorize a command, it is usually a good idea to learn where it's name comes from. For example, `cp` comes from copy. `usermod` means "User Modifiy" (at least I guess so).

Where does chmod come from, what does it mean?

Comment: Wikipedia is your friend for these: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod. Believe it or not there are topics for most of the commands.

Comment: You are right, it's say so right in the beginning

Comment: Consult the man pages, there is a wealth of information given in them. In your case, "man chmod".

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
change mode
```

It is the full form of the command. So basically you are changing the mode set as something to some other thing.

Read only permission to Read/Write permission, revoking read/write permission to just read only permission etc.

Comment: You're not IMO changing read to write or anything like that. You are just modifying the permissions for read/write/execute.

Comment: @PavelŠimerda, Thanks for pointing it out. I have edited the answer :)

Comment: When thinking about the terminology, it may also be helpful to know that permissions are stored together with file type (regular-file, directory, pipe, char-device, block-device, etc.) in a single integer field which is usually called the "mode" of the file. (`struct stat`'s `st_mode` in userspace; `struct inode`'s `i_mode` in the kernel).

Answer (score 3):

**CH**ange **MOD**e.

```
[root@localhost /]# apropos -e chmod -s 1
chmod (1)            - change file mode bits
[root@localhost /]#
```